# Using keys in order to obtain value from dictionary randomly C# unity

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I originally managed to create something wherein there would be a question (in an array) and the answers (in an array), and text values would be assigned to each randomly, with one of them being correct. Considering the nature of this, specifically the scale, I realised a dictionary would be more efficient. So I tried to manipulate my code and incorporate it with a dictionary. However, having done this it appears that the code does not work, specifically because 'the array index is out of range' (I used an int array in order to find the keys), and therefore the keys are not being referred to and thus no data comes out. I wondered if someone would be able to help me with this problem.

To do this I made 1 question script, and one dictionary. The idea was that I would return a value from the dictionary that would then be inserted into the question text .

(the dictionary in question is the questions one...the other one is for the buttons, but I presume after I obtain the answer for the questions, the buttons should be fairly similar if not the same)

### Dictionary

```
public class buttonDictionary : MonoBehaviour
{


public Dictionary<int, string> buttonA = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public Dictionary<int, string> questions = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public static int correctinput;
public static int index;
public static int key;
public static string answer1;
public int[] keys;
public static string answer;
public int wrongIndex;
private string wrongAnswer;
public static buttonDictionary arrays;
public static string question;
public static int correctButton;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    // Adds all of the answers to this scene into the dictionary 
    buttonA.Add(0, "I");
    buttonA.Add(1, "Like");
    buttonA.Add(2, "Dogs");
    buttonA.Add(3, "If");
    buttonA.Add(4, "They");
    buttonA.Add(5, "Like");
    buttonA.Add(6, "Me");
    buttonA.Add(7, "You");
    buttonA.Add(8, "QDW");
    buttonA.Add(9, "QDWQ");

    // Adds all of the questions to the dictionary 
    questions.Add(0, "d");
    questions.Add(1, "f");
    questions.Add(2, "f");
    questions.Add(3, "g");
    questions.Add(4, "ff");
    questions.Add(5, "gg");
    questions.Add(6, "ff");
    questions.Add(7, "gg");
    questions.Add(8, "hh");
    questions.Add(9, "ff");


     // Update is called once per frame

}

void Awake()
{
    arrays = this;
    // Copies all keys in the dictionary into an array and generates a random number, then generates a key
    int[] keys = new int[buttonA.Count];
    buttonA.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
    int index = Random.Range(0, keys.Length);
    GetAnswer1();
    GetQuestion1();
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
        Application.Quit();
}


// gets an index that refers to the key
public int He()
{
    int index = Random.Range(0, keys.Length);
    return index;

}
 // Gets the question 
public string GetQuestion1()
{
    var key = keys[index];
    question = questions[key];
    return question;
}
```

### question box

```
public class Question : MonoBehaviour
{ 

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    SetText();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void SetText()
{
    GameObject textBox = gameObject;
    textBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = buttonDictionary.question;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is kind of flawed in some ways. Can you be more specific in the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you re-declare a variablle in a inner scope of a method, like this:

```
public static int index;
// (...)

public int He()
{
    int index = Random.Range(0, keys.Length);
    return index;    
}
```

You are making a local variable that shadows the field you declared in the class body, they just aren't the same object. You stored the random integer in a variable named `index` that ceases to exist when you exit the method `He()`. (except that is returned by the method, but I can't see you using this return value anywhere in the code).

Then, when you try to access it later, in another method, like this:

```
public string GetQuestion1()
{
    var key = keys[index];
    // (...)
}
```

`index` here is, again, the field declared in the body class, that was never touched and have always the default value of 0. If what you want is to update the value of `index` in the `He` method for further reference, you should just refer to it, withoud declaring a type:

```
public int He()
{
    index = Random.Range(0, keys.Length);
    return index;    
}
```

Moreover, you are declaring all those fields as `static`, but I can't realize why you would want all instances of the buttons sharing the same correct keys, strings and indices... I don't really understand the overall logic of your solution, but I feel those fields shouldn't be static.

Comment: Ah okay I think I understand. What do you mean by the 'logic of my solution'? You, obviously, know more about coding than me, so do you believe the way I try to get a random object from the dictionary is insufficient? If so, is there a way you could guide me in the right direction? This is the first time I have ever done something marginally 'complex' (at least in my basic eyes), so that's why I am asking :D

Comment: You could write a class that aggregates all the data and logic related to a question object. You could have fields like: a string for the question text, a list of strings for the posible answers, and an int for the correct answer id. Then, you can write a method for displaying the question, that shuffles the answer ids.